# Writing a simple accumulator with pipes' WriterP

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

Using the pipes library, I want to write a program to read data from some source and accumulate it monoidally (say, with `Sum`). The easiest way to do this would be,

```hs
 import Control.Proxy as 
 import Data.Monoid (Sum)

 main = do
     let source = enumFromToS (0::Int) 5
     a <- runWriterT $ runProxy $ source >-> foldD Sum
     print a
```

Of course, while this works for small sources, large inputs will result in the dreaded stack overflow due to the lazy nature of `WriterT`'s accumulator.

Thankfully, it seems that `pipes` anticipates this, providing a `WriterP` proxy with a strict accumulator. Unfortunately, the documentation surrounding this proxy is pretty sparse. After a bit of poking around (and simplifying the problem to instead accumulate a 1 for each downstream element), I came to this program,

```hs
import Control.Proxy
import Control.Proxy.Trans.Writer
import Data.Monoid (Sum)

main = do
    let source = enumFromToS (0::Int) 5
    a <- runProxy $ runWriterK $ source >-> \x->tell (Sum 1::Sum Int)
    print a
```

Of course, this program doesn't even perform the simplified task correctly as it accumulates to 1 instead of 6. If I'm not mistaken, this behavior is explained by the fact that the pipe only reads one element before terminating. To repeat until the end of the input, I came up with the following,

```hs
import Control.Proxy
import Control.Proxy.Trans.Writer
import Data.Monoid (Sum)

main = do
    let source = enumFromToS (0::Int) 5
    a <- runProxy $ runWriterK $ source >-> fold Sum
    print a

fold :: (Monad m, Proxy p, Monoid w) => (a -> w) -> a' -> WriterP w p a' a a' a m r
fold f = go
  where go x = do a <- request x
                  tell $ f a
                  x' <- respond a
                  go x'
```

This code, however, returns an accumulator of 0. Why is this? Is there a function like my `fold` provided in `pipes`?

Given that many use-cases for `pipes` are long-running processes working with large data-sets, would it not make sense for the folds in `Control.Proxy.Prelude` to be built around the strict `WriterP` instead of `WriterT`? Currently it feels like the proxy transformers in `pipes` are second-class citizens, present but lacking many of the combinators that make `WriterT` so handy.

Comment: You are trying to reimplement `foldD` and `sumD` from the [folds](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes/3.1.0/doc/html/Control-Proxy-Prelude-Base.html#g:5) coming with `pipes`. Looking at the source code should clarify your doubt.

Comment: @DannyNavarro, I am aware of the existence of `foldD` and `sumD` and these were in fact the motivation for the first example. That being said, these both use `WriterT`, the laziness of which makes them unsuitable for large inputs. This is the reason I was playing around with `WriterP`.

Comment: Why not just use [the strict version of `WriterT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/0.3.0.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Strict.html)?

Comment: @C.A.McCann It does not fold things strictly enough.  When I have more time I plan on requesting an even stricter version be added to transformers.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez: Ah, now that I look at the source I see what you mean. The same goes for the strict `StateT`, I assume.

Comment: @C.A.McCann, the "strictness" (or lack thereof) of `Control.Monad.Trans.Writer.Strict` is something that has tripped me up numerous times in the past. I was under the impression that it wasn't even possible to write a strictly accumulating (e.g. forcing the `mappend`) `Writer` monad as you have nothing on which to `seq`.

Comment: @bgamari: Yeah. After looking at the source, I now realize that the "strict" versions are essentially the naive implementation, while the "lazy" version adds irrefutable patterns to be even *less* strict.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm adding a new answer because I've fixed this issue in `pipes-3.3`, which I just uploaded to Hackage.  The theory behind pipes shows that the global behavior you were expecting was the right behavior all along, and `WriterP` now  behaves globally so you can fold within a pipe.

I've modified your example to show you would implement it using `pipes-3.3`:

```
import Control.Proxy
import Control.Proxy.Trans.Writer

main = do
    let source = enumFromToS (0::Int) 5
    a <- runProxy $ execWriterK $ source >-> sumD
    print a
```

You can also now retrieve the results of a fold within a pipeline.  For example, this is perfectly valid:

```
chunksOf :: (Monad m, Proxy p) => Int -> () -> Pipe p a [a] m r
chunksOf n () = runIdentityP $ forever $ do
    -- The unitU discards the values that 'toListD' reforwards
    as <- execWriterK (takeB_ n >-> toListD >-> unitU) ()
    respond as
```

Here's an example usage:

```
>>> runProxy $ getLineS >-> takeWhileD (/= "quit") >-> chunksOf 3 >-> printD
1<Enter>
2<Enter>
3<Enter>
["1","2","3"]
4<Enter>
5<Enter>
6<Enter>
["4","5","6"]
quit
```

Sorry for getting the answer wrong the first time!

Comment: Thanks for the update! I'll try incorporating this approach shortly.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that proxy transformers behave locally, whereas the base monad behaves globally.  That means that `WriterP` has each proxy maintain its own accumulator, and the proxy that terminates first determines which accumulator returns.  The reason the accumulator returned `0` is because your enumerating pipe returned first and it was not accumulating anything.

The `WriterP` fold is strict only because I have control over that type (and not the one in `transformers`).  I never intended it to be the strict alternative to the lazy folds in the proxy prelude.  The correct strict alternative to use is `foldlD'`.

Note that `foldlD' mappend` is basically a strict `Writer` fold, particularly if you run the base `State` monad using `mempty` as the initial state.

In your case, you can do it even more easily using:

```
main = do
    let source = enumFromToS (0::Int) 5
    a <- (`runStateT` 0) $ runProxy $ source >-> foldlD' (+)
    print a
```

That will fold the input strictly.